# Sympy cannot take simple derivative with sympy.diff()

Tags: python, sympy

I was using sympy to check some of my calculations when I noticed that it was producing an incorrect output for a simple derivative. Below I will show the code and the output, and what it should have produced instead:

```
import sympy as sp
from sympy import *
A,x = sp.symbols('A,x')
diff(sqrt(A*x), (x,1))
```

Clearly the output should have been A / 2sqrt(A*x), however the output keeps giving me sqrt(A*x) / 2*x. I cannot understand what the cause of this might be. Any thoughts?

Comment: It is nearly the same except that your expected output would be undefined for `A == 0`

Answer (score 2):

The output is not incorrect. There can be many different ways to represent an expression that are equivalent or that are not equivalent given the potential for corner cases such as the case of `A = 0` noted in the comment.

This is the output that you get:

```
In [38]: A, x = symbols('A, x')

In [39]: diff(sqrt(A*x), x)
Out[39]: 
  _____
╲╱ A⋅x 
───────
  2⋅x
```

If you declare `A` to be positive then you will get a different form:

```
In [48]: A = symbols('A', positive=True)

In [49]: x = symbols("x")

In [50]: diff(sqrt(A*x), x)
Out[50]: 
 √A 
────
2⋅√x
```

By default `A` is not assumed to be positive (or even real).